# If String concatenation using + is implemented using StringBuilder then why are extra objects created during concatenation?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

If the following code:

```
String s = "a" + 1 + "b";// 1.
```

Is implemented using using StringBuilder equivalent to

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append("a").append(1).append("b");
```

then will extra objects "a" and "b" be created in 1 and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing it up a bit...

For the `+`-case, there will be an extra `"a1"`-object created when evaluating `"a" + 1` (right before concatenating `"a1"` with `"b"`). This extra object creation can be avoided when using the `append` method. Thats all.

The `"a"` and `"b"` will already be created during compile time. (Those constant literals will be present in the sting pool from the beginning.) But as you probably know, those constants will be created also in the `append` case.

Answer (score 5):

Your example will not actually use a `StringBuilder` because none of the elements are variables.  Because "a", 1, and "b" are all literals, the compiler will make a single `String` for you!  If, however, you included a variable in that `String` concatenation, then it would use a `StringBuilder` and would need separate `String`s for the concatenated elements.

For your example the compiler would create a single String literal:

```
const #2 = String       #21;    //  a1b

public void foo();
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=1
   0:   ldc     #2; //String a1b
   2:   astore_1
   3:   return
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 7: 0
   line 8: 3
```

Let's say we had instead written

```
public void bar(String c)
{
    String s = "a" + c + "b";// 1.
}
```

Now the compiler will need to create a `StringBuilder`, and it will use the a and b constant ASCII literals with the `StringBuilder`.

```
const #20 = Asciz       a;
const #22 = Asciz       b;

public void bar(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=3, Args_size=2
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   ldc     #4; //String a
   9:   invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava    /lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   12:  aload_1
   13:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   16:  ldc     #6; //String b
   18:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   21:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   24:  astore_2
   25:  return
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 7: 0
   line 8: 25
```

Comment: If the code is in Foo.java compiled to Foo.class, use `javap -c -v Foo` to get the decompilation output shown.  It is very instructive to do so, especially on simple examples like yours.  (I've just selected the interesting bits from the javap output.)

Comment: More to your answer, the a and b objects must be created in order to pass them as parameters to `StringBuilder.append()`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are wondering why it is more efficient in general to use `StringBuilder` instead of the `+` operator on Strings. In your example, the difference is negligible, but you have to consider larger problems, usually resulting from looping.

Take for example the following code:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
   s = s + "something";
}
```

No matter, if you use a `StringBuilder` to optimize this `+` operation or not, you create a `String` object to store in `s`. So each loop iteration will create a new `String` object, giving you a huge number of newly created objects.

In contrast, if you use a `StringBuilder` with `sb.append("something")` inside the loop, the `StringBuilder` is not required to create a `String` object for each loop iteration. It can freely wait to create one, until it is required after the loop.